# How do I trigger a command according to cron syntax while staying in the foreground?

Tags: bash, cron

I'm looking for a way to trigger a command according to the crontab syntax, while staying in the foreground.

A bit of context : the command will be run in a docker container. Staying in the foreground prevents the container to stop. I'm using a continuous deployment pipeline so I have no access to the system (so no docker run options, no systemd timer, no crontab). And finally the container orchestrator doesn't have schedule options.

I thought of these solutions, but they are not completely solving my problem:

- `watch` can only take time interval
- `while true : block + sleep`  workaround also takes only time intervals
- use a `while true` script and crontab inside the container but might bring other troubles

How can I accomplish this in a way that meets each of my needs?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? watch already does this and something has to have control of the view port, having random letter printed in the foreground isn't very intuitive. If you need to monitor something, it's better to use syslog.

Comment: The command will be run in a docker container. Staying in the foreground prevents the container to stop. I'm using a continuous deployment pipeline, I have no access to docker run options, and the orchestrator doesn't have schedule options.

Comment: @LuoLeKe without commenting on those ridiculous restrictions, you can use screen instead and run your command there. Or, if you want to be extra annoying, create the container every time it needs to run.

Comment: I need to run the script in a very specific location due to security issue, and I can't access the system directly, so I can"t use screen. The second option is not technically possible (unless a heavy workaround).

Comment: It's prooably not too hard to find or write a tool to convert a `crontab` expression to the number of seconds until the next occurrence, and then pass that to `watch`. I thought I just saw a Python library which understands `crontab` syntax, but I can't find the link right now. Would this be acceptable, and useful? The requirement to use `crontab` as input seems rather bewildering anyway; is this central to your use case?

Comment: The usual solution is to run `crond` in the background and have another job run in the foreground forever to satisfy Docker; is there a reason you are simply not doing this instead? Maybe that's what your last bullet point is already trying to say?)

Comment: @triplee Yes the python library would be very useful ! It can be a `crontab` syntax or something equivalent. Also writing the tool myself could be an interesting exercise.
About `crond` in the background and a non-stopping job in the foreground, I feel that I would have to spend quite some time setting log routing or resolving other unknown issues. The first solution seems better.

Comment: Belatedly, https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html. There are also various third-party libraries. Sorry for taking so long to get back to you.

Comment: I started to write it finally in bash and well it's not that easy to compute the next occurrence especially when you have multiple frequency conditions in your cron rule (ex: */25 */ 3 * * * )